# How to create a transposed data frame from another data frame

Tags: sql, scala, hive, apache-spark-sql

I create a dataframe DF from external file, which has the following schema:

> (id, field1, field2, field3) partition column: id

data example is

```
 000,  11_field1,  22_field2,  33_field3
 001, 111_field1, 222_field2, 333_field3
```

I want to create another dataframe from DF which schema is

```
 (id, fieleName, fieldValue)
```

data example is

```
000, field1,  11_field1
000, field2,  22_field2
000, field3,  33_field3
001, field1, 111_field1
001, field2, 222_field2
001, field3, 333_field3
```

Could anyone tell me how to get the new dataframe?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works for me.

Comment: Could you please up vote my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in `pyspark` like below using `explode` option

First import necessary libraries and functions

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
```

Say your data frame is `df`.

If you do `df.show()`

you should get result like below

```
+---+----------+----------+----------+
| id|    field1|    field2|    field3|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
|  0| 11_field1| 22_field2| 33_field3|
|  1|111_field1|222_field2|333_field3|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
```

Then map all columns you want to explode as 2 columns. Here you want all columns except id to explode. So, do the below

```
cols= df.columns[1:]
```

then convert the `data frame` to `rdd` like below

```
rdd = data.rdd.map(lambda x: Row(id=x[0], val=dict(zip(cols, x[1:]))))
```

To check how the rdd has been mapped do below

```
rdd.take()
```

you will get result like below

```
[Row(id=0, val={'field2': u'22_field2', 'field3': u'33_field3', 'field1': u'11_field1'}), Row(id=1, val={'field2': u'222_field2', 'field3': u'333_field3', 'field1': u'111_field1'})]
```

Then convert the `rdd` back to a `data frame` say `df2`

```
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd)
```

Then do `df2.show()`. you should get result like below

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|                 val|
+---+--------------------+
|  0|Map(field3 -> 33_...|
|  1|Map(field3 -> 333...|
+---+--------------------+
```

then register the data frame df2 as a temp table

```
df2.registerTempTable('mytempTable')
```

Then run a query like below on the data frame:

```
df3 = sqlContext.sql( """select id,explode(val) AS (fieldname,fieldvalue) from mytempTable""")
```

then do `df3.show()`, you should get the result as below

```
+---+---------+----------+
| id|fieldname|fieldvalue|
+---+---------+----------+
|  0|   field3| 33_field3|
|  0|   field2| 22_field2|
|  0|   field1| 11_field1|
|  1|   field3|333_field3|
|  1|   field2|222_field2|
|  1|   field1|111_field1|
+---+---------+----------+
```